# Logical equality expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

Suppose I have two boolean variables and want to know when they are both true or false, in other words, I need a [logical equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equality) operator.'

Every JS book suggests bitwise operators, and XOR operator does pretty much the same thing but inverted: it indicates whether boolean variables have different value. So I come up with an expression:

```
const a = true
const b = false
const c = !(a ^ b)
```

This code seems quite not obvious when reading. Is there a better and more obvious solution?

Comment: `Every JS book suggests bitwise operators`, which books are you reading :)

Comment: @DavinTryon ok Flanagan's book is not every book :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  const c = a === b
```

Just compare them.

Comment: That's a wonderful option! I am an idiot!

Comment: @pttsky there are no dumb questions, just dumb answers ... Glad to help :)